# Python list to store class instance?

Tags: python, list

Given a python class `class Student():` and a list `names = []`; then I want to create several instances of `Student()` and add them into the list `names`,

```
names = [] # For storing the student instances
class Student():
    def __init__(self, score, gender):
        self.score = score
        self.gender = gender
```

And now I want to check out the scores of all the male students, can I do it like this?

```
scores = []
for i in names:
    if i.gender ==  "Male":
        scores.append(i.score)
```

My question is: How to create a list that can (if could be done by any statement) store the instance of `Student`? Or rather, when I write `names = []`, how could I state every element in `names` is an instance of `Student` so that I can use the attributs of this element despite python is weak type? I hope I made myself clear ;)

Can I write like:

```
    for i in range(len(names)):
        student = Student()
        student = names[i]
        if student.gender == "Male":
            # Whatever
```

I guess not...

Comment: Responding to your edit: No, you can't write that because you're calling `Student()` without arguments although it takes 2. If you delete that line, it will work.

Comment: @sepp2k, yes, the arguments do not match in the Student construtor, so this will cuase errors. well, I think I should think over my problem becuase now I have difficulties in expressing my problem, what I posted was not my point

Comment: if you think through your code some more you might understand where it's failing. The line `student = Student()` attempts to create a new `Student` instance and store it in the variable `student`. This will fail, because the constructor is missing some required arguments. I think you are trying to declare the type of `student`? You don't have to do that in Python. It will work it out for you at runtime. Notice also that you can iterate directly over the elements of `names` with `for student in names: ...` .

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Did you try your code above? It should work fine. You can condense it into:

```
scores = [ student.name for student in names if student.gender == "Male" ]
```

Note that calling the list `names` is misleading, since it is a list of `Student` instances.

You can't define the list to be a list of Student instances; that's not how Python works.

Are you asking how to create the list that you've called `names`?

```
names = [ ]
for ( score, gender ) in <some-data-source>:
    names.append( Student( score, gender ) )
```

which is of course equivalent to

```
names = [ Student( score, gender ) for score, gender in <some-data-source> ]
```

and in turn to

```
names = [ Student( *row ) for row in <some-data-source> ]
```

If you need to do a lot of processing for each row then you can either move the processing into a separate function or use a `for` loop.

```
def process_row( row ):
    ...
    return score, gender

names = [ Student( *process_row( row ) ) for row in <some-data-source> ]
```

---

Responding to your edit, I think you are trying to declare the types of variables in Python. You wrote:

```
for i in range(len(names)):
    student = Student()
    student = names[i]
    if student.gender == "Male":
        # Whatever
```

What is the purpose of the line `student = Student()` -- are you trying to declare the type of the variable `student`? Don't do that. The following will do what you intended:

```
for student in students:
   if student.gender == "Male":
       # Whatever
```

Notice several things:

1. We don't need to iterate over `range(n)` and then look up each instance in `names`; iterating over every element of a container is the purpose of a `for` loop.
2. You don't need to make any claims about what `student` is -- it could be a string, a boolean, a list, a `Student`, whatever. This is *dynamic typing*. Likewise, `students` doesn't have to be a list; you can iterate over any *iterable*.
3. When you write `student.gender`, Python will get the `gender` attribute of `student`, or raise an exception if it doesn't have one.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I see your points, but I dont know how to express my problems, annoying though

Comment: the condensed look fairly neat and concise, in some cases, the if statement may invovle a bunch of TODOs, could this form works, might not be so straightforword??

Comment: Well, means a lot of things to do :) i.e. if statement1, then do a lot of things

Answer (score 7):

First of all python is *not* weakly typed. It is however dynamically typed so you can't specify an element type for your list.

However this does not prevent you from accessing an object's attributes. This works just fine:

```
names = [Student(1,"Male"), Student(2,"Female")]
scores = []
for i in names:
    if i.gender ==  "Male":
        scores.append(i.score)
```

It is however more pythonic to write this using a list comprehension:

```
names = [Student(1,"Male"), Student(2,"Female")]
scores = [i.score for i in names if i.gender == "Male"]
```

Comment: Actually, according to most definitions I think Python *is* weakly typed -- it supports overloading, implicit type conversions, polymorphism... If that isn't "weak typing", what is? Admittedly the term doesn't mean much anyway.

Comment: I'd also say has Python dynamic types. The OP knows only the opposite: *static* types. It seems that *strong* and *weak* are rather bad names for very similar concepts ..

Comment: No. weak type means that there's no big difference within types. So you can add string variable to number as though it was a number too.
In python you MUST aware of variable type. But it can be found runtime only or dynamically.

Comment: @Odomontois: Can you give an example of a language which is weakly typed by your definition?

Comment: @katrielalex Perl is common example.

Comment: @katrielalex, you might find this article enlightening: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=7590

Comment: @Aaron: thanks for the article. I'm not sure I see what it's trying to say; I think it's that Python is dynamically typed? @Odomontois: well, I'm no Perl expert but I'm fairly sure that even that most horrendous of language *distinguishes* between numbers and strings! It merely overloads a lot of common operations so that you don't need to worry about the difference. Notice that there are implicit type conversions in Python (`1+1.==2.`), though they are uncommon.

Comment: @katrielalex: Note that he said "no *big* difference". A language where there's no difference at all (i.e. there are no types) would be untyped, not just weakly typed. Bash script would be an example of an untyped language.

Comment: @katrielalex, in your example, both of the operands are numbers, though different types of numbers. Weakly-typed languages have implicit conversions between orthogonal types, e.g. strings and numbers.

Answer (score 6):

I'm fairly new to OOP, but does this not do what you want quite nicely? `name_list` is a class variable, and every time you create a new `Student` object, it gets added to `Student.name_list`. Say for example you had a method `cheat(self)` which you wanted to perform on the third student, you could run `Student.name_list[2].cheat()`. Code:

```
class Student():
    name_list = []
    def __init__(self, score, gender):
        Student.name_list.append(self)
        self.score = score
        self.gender = gender

    #this is just for output formatting
    def __str__(self):
        return "Score: {} || Gender: {}".format(self.score, self.gender)

#again for output formatting
def update(): print([str(student) for student in Student.name_list])

update()
Student(42, "female")
update()
Student(23, "male")
update()
Student(63, "male")
Student(763, "female")
Student("over 9000", "neutral")
update()
```

Output:

```
[]
['Score: 42 || Gender: female']
['Score: 42 || Gender: female', 'Score: 23 || Gender: male']
['Score: 42 || Gender: female', 'Score: 23 || Gender: male', 'Score: 63 || Gender: male', 'Score: 763 || Gender: female', 'Score: over 9000 || Gender: neutral']
```